GPG doesn't want to import my private key
I've been trying to export my private key from my laptop to my phone(termux). But whenever I tried importing the private key on the phone, the gpg just throws an error at me:
> gpg --import private.pgp
 gpg: key AAAAAAAAAA: "name <name@name>" imported
 gpg: key AAAAAAAAAA/BBBBBBBBBB: error sending to agent: A locale function failed
 gpg: key AAAAAAAAAA/CCCCCCCCCC: error sending to agent: A locale function failed
 gpg: error reading 'private.gpg': A locale function failed
 gpg: import from 'private.pgp' failed: A locale function failed
 gpg: Total number processed: 0
 gpg:              unchanged: 1
 gpg:       secret keys read: 1

I do not have much experience with GPG,  and the internet doesn't help much either, so I am clueless as to how to solve the problem.
EDIT:
After researching some more, I found the '--debug-level' flag, which did help me close in on the problem:
gpg: DBG: chan_6 <- INQUIRE PINENTRY_LAUNCHED 10984 curses 1.3.1 /dev/pts/0 xterm-256color - 20600/10417/10417 10417/10417 0
gpg: pinentry launched (10984 curses 1.3.1 /dev/pts/0 xterm-256color - 20600/10417/10417 10417/10417 0)
gpg: DBG: chan_6 -> END
gpg: DBG: chan_6 <- ERR 83886246 A locale function failed <Pinentry>
gpg: key AAAAAAAAAA/BBBBBBBBBB: error sending to agent: A locale function failed

Still, I was not able to find any information regarding that problem, I tried every solution from every related post and still no luck.

Maybe your phone uses an outdated version of GPG. Check versions and check encryption method.
